# Chromecast receiving input from multiple devices on RemoteCast

Tags: android, chromecast

I realize that it is possible to create a Custom receiver in order to receive messages from multiple devices.

Is it possible to use the Remotecast (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote)  API in order to run an application on the Chromecast which receives input from multiple devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Remote Display, you are running a special receiver on the cast device which only communicates with the device that set it up, so other devices cannot communicate with that receiver directly. The workaround is to communicate with the sender device that set up the remote display to influence the experience on the cast device.